# Removing elements from an array while iterating in while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I want to get random names from the `nameArray` and each time delete that element, so that in the end, I have got all names and the `nameArray` is empty. Nothing displays in the console.

```
let i;
let nameArray = ['Chara','Lisette','Corine','Kevin','Carlee'];
while(i < nameArray.length){
let name = nameArray[ Math.floor( Math.random() * nameArray.length )];
   console.log(name);
   delete nameArray[i];
 }
```

Comment: You made an infinite loop! This statement `(i < nameArray.length)` is always correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is never initialized nor updated, so the while loop doesn't make too much sense.
You can try this instead:

```js
let nameArray = ['Chara','Lisette','Corine','Kevin','Carlee'];
while(nameArray.length > 0) { // while the array is not empty
    let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * nameArray.length); // pick a random element index
    console.log(nameArray[i]); // print the element
    nameArray.splice(i, 1); // remove the element from the array
}
```